# Using Mathjax in multiple spots (different bootstrap tabs) on webpage causes error

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, mathjax

I am making a website with Django. I am using Bootstrap for scaffolding, and I have some Bootstrap tabs on this one page. One of the tabs has a `div` with math which utilizes MathJax, and another tab has that same `div` with the same math (one of the tabs has extra stuff on it, that's why there are both tabs).

Whichever of the `div`'s is higher in the HTML page (though order doesn't matter for the layout because they are tabs so only one shows at a time anyway) is rendered correctly by MathJax, but the other one appears to have an error (instead of rendering the math correctly, it outlines certain parts of it in a rectangular border).

Why might multiple tabs of math conflict with each other when MathJax is trying to render them?

https://jsfiddle.net/fwm03o9w/2/ to show the code

EDIT:

Where it should be rendering but isn't, the HTML instead has the raw stuff.

```
<span style="display: inline-block;" id="MathJax-Span-743" class="noError">P(k, 1) =1-k\tag{2}\label{2}</span>
```

The corresponding HTML in the tab that it DOES render correctly instead has a bunch of `span`'s with `id`'s MathJax-Span-110 through MathJaxSpan-119 and all the styling that gives that same equation from above the look and awesomeness of MathJax. So the question comes down to why MathJax worked its magic on this one, but not on the other pane which came later in the HTML file.

EDIT 2:

http://tylersc.com/problems/1/ Click the tabs "All" and "Proof" to see the correct and incorrect behavior respectively.

Comment: The class `noerror` indicates an error; ok, actually it indicates the NoErrros extension which instead of an error shows the plain source. My guess would be that you've used the same tag elsewhere (leading to duplicate IDs in the HTML and thus errors).

Comment: can you post the code? in the link you gave there is no id=MathJax-Span-743. Furthermore, maybe the problem is that you haven't closed a </div> or something similar

Comment: I posted a link to the site. The page's HTML will show what I was talking about. Thanks for the suggestion!